# Getting 'not defined' on libraries after webpacking

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I'm trying to compile my **server.jsx** using webpack. It compiles, but then when I run the file i get "... not defined" errors. Like : "express is not defined". If i inspect into the compiled source i can see that express is obviously an undefined variable.
Here's my **webpack.config**:

```
{
   target: 'node',
   entry: {
    app: "./src/app/app.js",
   },
   output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist/assets/",
    filename: "./js/app.js"
   }
   ,
   externals: [
    /^(?!\.|\/).+/i,
   ],
   module: {
       loaders: [{
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]"
       },
       {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["react-hot", 'babel?'+JSON.stringify(
            {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                "plugins": [
                    "syntax-class-properties",
                    "syntax-decorators",
                    "syntax-object-rest-spread",
                    "transform-class-properties",
                    "transform-object-rest-spread"
                ]
            }
        )]
       }]
   }
};
```

I thought that maybe I should use *libraryTarget*, but I really don't know what am i suposed to do with that. For example: if I want to use express and mongoose, where should I set it?

**Edit**
**Server.jsx:**

```
'use strict';
require('babel-core/register'); 
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import React from 'react';
import store from '../app/store'
import { RouterContext, match } from 'react-router';
import routes from '../app/routes/routes.jsx';
import { createLocation } from 'history';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
...
```

Comment: can you show us your `server.jsx`?

Comment: I edited the question @erik-sn